# JSON result does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json

I have encountered an error while creating my JSON action.

The problem is that the lower JsonResult is being underlined with the message 'JSON result does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. I am not entirely sure how to fix this.

```
public JsonResult GetEventInfo(MVCEventCalendarContext context)
        {
            var events = context.EventInfo.ToList();
            return new JsonResult();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

JsonResult is going to convert the value of your output to JSON and as a result is expecting something to output.

You probably want to return the events to the caller. If so, pass the events variable into the JsonResult() function, as follows:

`return new JsonResult(events);`

As an aside, if you are serializing a collection to JSON, use `.ToArray()` instead of `.ToList()` if that's the final output. It's faster.